# How to replicate behavior in repeatable method?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Current (work in progress):

[image]

Current WIP with backgroundColor set to black:

[image]

Goal:

[image]

The goal I'm trying to replicate is the picture above. Now to make it repeatable my first inclination is to create a class with a custom StackLayout which contains an array of labels. Five labels per rectangle (perhaps more to create the shell of the rectangle to ensure clarity), and there being four rectangles total comes out to 20 distinct labels.

4 distinct rectangles, with slight spacing between each other complete rectangle (notice the spacing between the four rectangles so we know each one is unique), with 5 columns each. Ideally a parameter is passed through binding for each individual rectangle in the row.

If a 1 is passed, 1 cell is colored green, and the rest are colored grey.
2, 2 cells are colored a lighter green, the rest grey.
3, 3 cells colored yellow, the rest grey,
etc.

In this way the analysis of the rectangle can be done by checking its color or the number of bars colored.

Fresh off the Xamarin.Forms novice bus. Reading through their developer intros/hands-on pdf walking through some basics but I haven't found what I'm looking for quite yet.

Here are examples of what I am thinking is the optimal implementation (w/ the most minimal Xamarin.Forms experience)

The hope here is that someone can point to/show a structure capable of emulating and creating the row of rectangles as they are shown in the image. I realize the picture can't be replicated as shown - just want to know the proper way to do this in Xamarin.Forms as I don't know if this is the best/optimal way to go about this.

Example page:

```
public class examplePage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<CustomCells> cellColl { get; set; }

    public examplePage()
    {
        ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCells));
        cellColl.Add(new CustomCells { rectOne = "1", rectTwo = "4", rectThree = "2", rectFour = "5" });
        listView.ItemsSource = Devices;
        var listViewLayout = new StackLayout();
        listViewLayout.Children.Add(listView);
        Content = listViewLayout;
    }
}
```

Example class:

```
public class CustomCells : ViewCell
{
    public CustomCells()
    {
        /* TO-DO FORM STRUCTURE HERE */

    // example for examples sake
    var newLayout = new StackLayout()
    {
        Spacing = 1,
        Children =
            {
                new Label
                {
                    Text = " \n ",
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
                },

                new Label
                {
                    Text = " \n ",
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
                }
            }
    };

    //
    //  Create layouts
    //
    var verticaLayout = new StackLayout();
    var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout() { BackgroundColor = Color.White };

    //
    //  Set bindings
    //
    // Sample binding...
        rowOne.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("ID"));

    //
    //  Set properties for desired design
    //
    horizontalLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
    horizontalLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
    horizontalLayout.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

    //
    //  Add views to the view hierarchy
    //
    horizontalLayout.Children.Add(newLayout);

    //
    //  Add to parent view
    //
    View = horizontalLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: if each rectangle is just a box with no text, I would probably create a Grid with 20 columns, with each column containing a BoxView.

Comment: @Jason Grid using columns with BoxViews seems to be the ticket. Updated OP with latest. How to shade only behind the columns as opposed to the entire grid being shaded (see WIP w/ blk background)? Or is it better form to resize the grid?

Comment: not sure - you could try nesting a solid BoxView inside of a shaded one